# ¿Cómo descodificar los parámetros "categories" y "trigger" de un iCalendar?

Tags: python, encoding, icalendar

Quiero extraer información de un archivo **.ics** y tengo problemas con ciertos parámetros. Al extraer **"categories"** me aparece la información codificada, y con el parámetro **"trigger"** directamente no consigo extraer nada. He probado bastantes alternativas y ninguna con resultado.

```
import icalendar
from icalendar import Calendar, Event, vCalAddress, vText
from datetime import datetime
from pathlib import Path
import os

datos = {"CATEGORIES": [],
         "DTSTART": [],
         "SUMMARY": [],
         "DESCRIPTION": [],
         "TRIGGER": [],
         }

e = open('C:/Users/XXX/PycharmProjects/XXX/Calendario ALEMANIA.ics', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
ecal = icalendar.Calendar.from_ical(e.read())
for component in ecal.walk():
    if component.name == "VEVENT":
        categories = component.get("categories")
        datos["CATEGORIES"].append(categories)
        dtstart = component.decoded("dtstart")
        datos["DTSTART"].append(dtstart)
        summary = component.get("summary")
        datos["SUMMARY"].append(summary)
        description = component.decoded("description")
        datos["DESCRIPTION"].append(description)
        trigger = component.get("trigger")
        datos["TRIGGER"].append(trigger)

e.close()
print(datos)
```

Obtengo éste resultado en las dos categorias mencionadas:

```
{'TRIGGER': [None], 'CATEGORIES': [<icalendar.prop.vCategory object at 0x0000011240C056C0>]}
```

Cuando realmente (info del .ics) debería darme:

```
{'TRIGGER': [-PT15M], 'CATEGORIES': [Categoría Roja]}
```

He probado con muchas funciones y NO CONSIGO NADA... Algunas de ellas:

```
.decode('utf-8') , component.decode("categories") , .from_ical() , .ical()...
```

¿Alguien que pueda ayudarme?
Saludos

Comment: ¿puedes proporcionar un enlace del cual descargar un fichero .ics de ejemplo para que podamos hacer alguna prueba sobre él?

Comment: Si, aquí dejo otro ics que tengo de prueba. https://we.tl/t-2ZlDzMf1RS

Comment: Vaya.. te importaría probar con éste otro? : https://we.tl/t-HHi5DCKodg  Me he asegurado que contenga dichos parámetros.

Answer (score 0):

El problema particular de lo que te ocurre con las categorías es que `component.get("categories")` lo que te devuelve es un objeto que contiene un campo llamado `cats`, el cual es una lista de otros objetos de tipo vText, que deben ser convertidos en cadenas.

El problema más general es que cada uno de los campos que vas obteniendo con `.get()` o con `.decode()` requiere un procesamiento ligeramente diferente. Por ejemplo:

- "categories" requiere ser convertido, de objeto con campo `.cats`  a una lista de cadenas
- "summary" requiere ser convertido de tipo `vText` a cadena
- "dtstart" requiere probablemente ser convertido de tipo `datetime` a una cadena (depende de cómo lo vayas a usar luego, pero a menos que vayas a hacer aritmética con fechas posiblemente te sea más útil como cadena, por ejemplo si piensas volcarlo a disco o a JSON)
- "trigger" análogamente también debe ser convertido pues, aunque en el fichero .ics de entrada aparece como una cadena tal que "-PT15M", esa cadena en realidad significa un `deltatime`, es decir, una cantidad de tiempo relativa a otra (15 minutos antes de que empiece el día, es decir, a las 23:45 del día anterior)

### Funciones auxiliares

La forma más genérica de procesar estas cosas es la siguiente. Primero definimos una función separada para cada posible campo y cada función se ocupa de extraer y procesar adecuadamente el campo en cuestión:

```
def extraer_categories(component):
    categories = component.get("categories")
    if categories:
      # Convertrilo en lista de cadenas
      return [str(cat) for cat in categories.cats]
    else:
      # o en cadena vacia si no hay categorías
      return []

def extraer_dtstart(component):
    # Convertir deltatime en cadena
    return  str(component.decoded("dtstart"))

def extraer_summary(component):
    # convertir vText en cadena
    return str(component.get("summary"))

def extraer_description(component):
    # Convertir descripcion en cadena, suponiendo utf8 encoding
    return str(component.decoded("description"), "utf8")

def extraer_trigger(component):
    # Convertir el deltatime en cadena
    trigger = component.get("trigger")
    if trigger:
      return str(trigger.dt)
    else:
      return ""
```

Lo anterior es un ejemplo, en tu caso quizás quieras aplicar otras conversiones dependiendo del uso que vayas a dar al resultado.

Una vez tenemos esas funciones definidas, podemos escribir unos diccionarios que actúen de "mapa" de qué función es la que hay que llamar para extraer cada campo. Las claves del diccionario son los nombres de los campos y los valores son las funciones que hay que invocar. De hecho necesitamos diferentes mapas para procesar los componentes de tipo "VEVENT" y los de timpo "VALARM" pues por lo que he visto en tu ejemplo los triggers aparecen solo en los "VALARM", mientras que las categorías aparecen solo en los "VEVENT". Estos diccionarios-mapa pueden ser así:

```
mapa_extractores_vevent = {
    "CATEGORIES": extraer_categories,
    "DTSTART": extraer_dtstart,
    "SUMMARY": extraer_summary,
    "DESCRIPTION": extraer_description,
    "TRIGGER": extraer_trigger,
}
mapa_extractores_alarm = {
    "DESCRIPTION": extraer_description,
    "TRIGGER": extraer_trigger,
}
```

Ahora ya tenemos todo listo para escribir una función que reciba un componente (sólo uno) y extraiga del mismo la información deseada, retornando un diccionario con la información extraida (o bien None si el componente no se reconoce de un tipo válido). Para hacer esta función iteramos por los diccionario-mapa que acabo de definir, y vamos así llamando a cada función que ha de extraer cada campo:

```
def extraer_campos(component):
    dic = {}
    if component.name == "VEVENT":
      mapa = mapa_extractores_vevent
    elif component.name == "VALARM":
      mapa = mapa_extractores_alarm
    else:
      return None

    for campo, funcion in mapa.items():
        dic[campo] = funcion(component)
    return dic
```

### Solución final

Con ayuda de esa función el código que hace lo que tú planteabas inicialmente en tu pregunta sería éste:

```
datos = {"CATEGORIES": [],
         "DTSTART": [],
         "SUMMARY": [],
         "DESCRIPTION": [],
         "TRIGGER": [],
         }
for component in ecal.walk():
    dic = extraer_campos(component)
    if not dic:  # Nos saltamos los componentes no reconocidos
      continue
    for clave, valor in dic.items():
      datos[clave].append(valor)
```

Aplicando esto a tu ejemplo con datos de ALEMANIA, el resultado en la variable `datos` sería el siguiente (he truncado las descripciones que son muy largas):

```
{'CATEGORIES': [
    [],
    [],
    ['Categoría roja'],
    [],
    ['Categoría roja'],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    []],
 'DTSTART': [
    '2021-01-25 09:00:00+01:00',
    '2022-05-17 17:00:00+02:00',
    '2022-12-12 12:30:00+01:00',
    '2022-09-12 12:00:00+02:00',
    '2022-11-28 18:00:00+01:00',
    '2022-11-14 11:30:00+01:00',
    '2022-11-02 11:00:00+01:00',
    '2022-11-07 12:00:00+01:00',
    '2022-11-07 12:30:00+01:00',
    '2022-11-07 12:30:00+01:00',
    '2022-11-07 13:00:00+01:00',
    '2022-11-07 13:00:00+01:00',
    '2022-11-07 13:00:00+01:00',
    '2022-11-07 13:00:00+01:00',
    '2022-11-07 13:00:00+01:00',
    '2022-11-07 13:00:00+01:00'],
 'SUMMARY': [
    'ECOLAB_DE',
    'POWER ONLINE-HANDEL_DE',
    'WENKO_DE',
    'FEEL ZEN-CLEANING_DE',
    'METRO_DE',
    'BR TRADING_DE',
    'REINLINE_DE',
    'Kohler Lebensmittelhandel_DE',
    'KIWATEC GmbH_DE',
    'HYPAFOL GmbH_DE',
    'POLLER GmbH_DE',
    'UDO BAk R GmbH_DE',
    'hygi.de GmbH & Co_DE',
    'Endres GmbH & Co KG_DE',
    'Globus Fachmä rkte GmbH & Co.KG_DE',
    'Esmeyer GmbH & Co. KG_DE'],
 'DESCRIPTION': [
    'recepcion...',
    'Jörg..',
    'Frank..',
    'Reminder',
    'Brigit...',
    'Ralitsa...',
    'Tomasz...',
    'Reminder',
    'Reinline...',
    'CONTACTO IVACE...',
    'Reminder',
    'KIWATEC GmbH...',
    'Reminder',
    'CONTACTO IVACE',
    'CONTACTO IVACE',
    'CONTACTO IVACE',
    'CONTACTO IVACE',
    'CONTACTO IVACE',
    'CONTACTO IVACE',
    'CONTACTO IVACE'],
 'TRIGGER': ['',
    '',
    '',
    '-1 day, 23:45:00',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '-1 day, 23:45:00',
    '',
    '',
    '-1 day, 23:55:00',
    '',
    '-1 day, 23:55:00',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    ''
  ]
}
```

**Observa** cómo salen correctamente las categorías en los componentes que las tenía. Observa cómo la fecha sale en forma de cadena ISO. Finalmente los triggers salen también en forma de cadena como "-1day 23:45:00"

**Nota** ya que los triggers solo aparecen en eventos de tipo VALARM y no en los VEVENT he tenido que procesar ambos tipos de evento, por lo que en el resultado salen ambos tipos mezclados. Quizás quieras "unificarlos" añadiendo al evento su correspondiente alarma, pero no tengo claro dónde se almacena esa correspondencia (quizás simplemente una VALARM se aplica al evento anterior).

### Otra solucion

Aunque la respuesta anterior resuelve tu enfoque, no sé si este enfoque es el más correcto. Quizás en lugar de guardar el resultado como un diccionario lleno de listas pueda tener más sentido que el resultado sea una lista que contiene diccionarios. Esto sería fácil de implementar con las funciones auxiliares ya hechas. Quedaría así:

```
datos = []
for component in ecal.walk():
        dic = extraer_campos(component)
        if dic:
          datos.append(dic)
```